# Newbie: query amazon s3 database in Android client (Java)

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new in Amazon S3 service. I have an **Amazon S3 database**, the directory(bucket) structure is like:

```
-All bucket 
  -MyCompany
    -MyProduct 
      -Product_1
        - sub1_prod1
        - sub1_prod2
        ...
      -Product_2
        - sub2_prod1
        - sub2_prod2
        ...
```

As you see above, under `MyProduct` bucket I have several product buckets (**e.g.** `Product_1`), under each of the product bucket I have several sub-product(e.g. `sub1_prod1`). Each sub-product contains multiple files.

Now, I want to implement Java code in my Android client to **query all my products** under `MyProduct` bucket, how can I do this? I am using [AmazonS3Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html) class provided by [Amazon Android SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/).

**P.S.**:

I am able to create my `AmazonS3Client` object by using my credential.

```
AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(myCred);
```

I know how to upload files to S3 bucket in java code, but I am not sure how to query the S3 database & get the result in my Android client, that's to **get all the file names** under each sub_product bucket.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an Amazon S3 database

IMHO, Amazon S3 is not a database, any more than a directory of files is a database. You may wish to consider other Amazon AWS services that are actual databases, such as DynamoDB or RDS.

> that's to get all the file names under each sub_product bucket

By reading the documentation, it would appear that you will need to use some flavor of `listObjects()`.

The brute-force approach would be to use [the `listObjects()` that just takes the bucket name](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#listObjects%28java.lang.String%29). That will give you a list of everything, and you would need to sort them into the tree structure yourself.

The less-brute-force approach would be to use [the `listObjects()` that takes the bucket name and a prefix](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#listObjects%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), or [the `listObjects()` that takes a `ListObjectsRequest` parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#listObjects%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest%29). To use filesystem terms, this will tell you the files and subdirectories in that directory. This way, you can download the pieces more easily. However, this may require a lot of HTTP requests.

Comment: thanks, actually, I know there are listObjects() methods in the AmazonS3Client class doc, but I don't know how to create the e.g. prefix, how to create the parameter. For the listObjects() which takes bucket name, what is the format for the bucket name? e.g. "All bucket/MyCompany/MyProduct" ? Things like these are not clear to me, so some sample code would be more preferred.

Comment: @Leem.fin: "For the listObjects() which takes bucket name, what is the format for the bucket name?" -- it's the name of your bucket. I have no idea what you named your bucket. "e.g. "All bucket/MyCompany/MyProduct" ?" -- AFAIK, bucket names cannot have slashes in them. However, you claim to know how to store files in S3, so therefore you already know what your bucket names are.

Comment: @CommonsWare can u pls try to help me how to find object name and bucket name for video play from amazon link ?